# Using regular expressions to remove relative path slashes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am trying to remove all the relative image path slashes from a chunk of HTML that contains several other elements.

For example

```
<img src="../../../../images/upload/1/test.jpg />
```

would need to become

```
<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/website/images/upload/1/test.jpg" />
```

I was thinking of writing this as a rails helper, and just passing the entire block into the method, and make using Nokogiri or Hpricot to parse the HTML instead, but I don't really know.

Any help would be great

Cheers
Adam

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you specify regular expressions?  They aren't very well suited to the problem; I think you're putting the cart before the horse.  You might get better responses if you edit your title to remove the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel, when the builtin 'uri' lib can do that for you:

```
require 'uri'
main_path = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/website/a/b/c"
relative_path = "../../../../images/upload/1/test.jpg"

URI.join(main_path, relative_path).to_s
  # ==> "http://s3.amazonaws.com/images/upload/1/test.jpg"
```

Comment: Handy that. I thought you'd have to use URI.parse(...).path and some File.expand_path to do this.

Comment: URI.join() is how I do it all the time. As an alternate to URI, Addressable::URI is a nice module because it is a bit more full-featured, especially if you have to work with IDNA-type URLs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Answer (score 3):

One way to construct an absolute path given the absolute URL of the page and a relative path found on that page:

```
pageurl = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/website/foo/bar/baz/quux/index.html'
relative = '../../../../images/upload/1/test.jpg'
absolute = pageurl.sub(/\/[^\/]*$/, '')
relative.split('/').each do |d|
  if d == '..'
    absolute.sub!(/\/[^\/]*$/, '')
  else
    absolute << "/#{d}"
  end
end
p absolute
```

Alternatively, you could cheat a bit:

```
'http:/'+File.expand_path(File.dirname(pageurl.sub(/^http:/, ''))+'/'+relative)
```

Answer (score 1):

This chunk might help:

```
html = '<img src="../../../../images/upload/1/test.jpg />'
absolute_uri = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/website/images"
html.gsub(/(\.\.\/)+images/, absolute_uri)
```

Comment: Of course, this only works if all of the images are under the same path and we know this path beforehand.